# What is '<?' operator in C++?

Tags: c++

In the following code can somebody please tell me what the "< ?" operator is doing?

I don't even know how to search google for this thing and I can't find it anywhere in any reference. The code also doesn't compile with the gcc compiler.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

#define REP(i,n) for (int i = 0; i < (n); i++)
#define REPD(i,n) for (int i = (n) - 1; i >= 0; i--)

char buf[110];
const int inf = 1000000000;

int main() {
    int zzz;
    gets(buf);
    sscanf(buf, "%d", &zzz);
    REP(zz,zzz) {
        map<string,int> num;
        int s;
        gets(buf);
        sscanf(buf, "%d", &s);
        REP(i,s) {
            gets(buf);
            num[buf] = i;
        }
        int q;
        gets(buf);
        sscanf(buf, "%d", &q);
        int res[100], mil[100], mir[100];
        REP(i,s)
            res[i] = 0;
        REP(i,q) {
            gets(buf);
            int k = num[buf];
            mil[0] = inf;
            REP(j,s-1)
                mil[j+1] = mil[j] <? res[j];
            mir[s-1] = inf;
            REPD(j,s-1)
                mir[j] = mir[j+1] <? res[j+1];
            REP(j,s)
                if (j == k)
                    res[j] = inf;
                else
                    res[j] <?= (mil[j] <? mir[j]) + 1;
        }
        int r = inf;
        REP(i,s)
            r <?= res[i];
        printf("Case #%d: %d\n", zz+1, r);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: That isn't a thing in standard C++.